# Invariance of syndetic set in topological semigroup

Tags: topological-groups, topological-semigroups

Let $T$ be a topological semigroup.  $A\subseteq T$ is syndetic, if there is compact set $K\subseteq T$ with $T=KA$.

Let syndetic set $A\subseteq T$ and $g\in T$ be given. I think that $Ag^{-1}=\{y: yg\in A\}$ is syndetic. Indeed  since $A$ is syndetic, there is compact set $K$ with $T=KA$. For every $t\in T$, since $tg\in KA$, hence $t\in KAg^{-1}$. This implies that $T= KAg^{-1}$ i.e.

if $A$ is syndetic, then $B=Ag^{-1}$ is syndetic.

What can say about situation of $Ag$, is it syndetic?

Please help me to know it.

Comment: $Ag$ is also syndetic precisely by your argument applied to the element $g':=g^{-1}$.

Comment: @Ruy Thanks. But $T$ is semigroup.

Comment: $Ag$ is syndetic if there is compact set $K\subseteq T$ such that $T=KAg$ that is, for every $t\in T$, there are $k\in K$ and $a\in A$ with $t=kag$.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question the forst time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on $g$ in the following way:

> **Proposition.** Let $A$ be syndetic. Then $Ag$ is syndetic iff $Tg = T$.

Indeed, if $Ag$ is syndetic, then $KAg = T$ for some compact $K$.

Then $KAg \subseteq Tg$, so that $T = Tg$.

Conversely, if $Tg = T$, and $KA = T$, then $KAg = Tg = T$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give more detail for your proof, please. Since $A$ is syndetic, there is compact set $K_0$ with $T=K_0A$ and by syndetic of $Ag$ there is compact set $K_1$ with $T=K_1Ag$.  Does it imply that $T=Tg$? Please give more detail.

Comment: You don't need to use that $A$ is syndetic for this. More explicitly, $T = K_1Ag \subseteq Tg \subseteq T$ and so $T = Tg$

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.  Take the semigroup $T=\{0,1\}$, viewed as a subgroup of the **multiplicative** integers, and equipped with the discrete topology.  Then $A=\{1\}$ is syndetic (take $K=T$), but if $g=0$, then  $Ag$ is not.